# CakePHP HABTM condition

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, has-and-belongs-to-many

I want to make a condition on my HABTM attributes
I have the following HABTM relations in CakePHP 2.x:

**Practise.php**

```php
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Attribute' => array(
        'className' => 'Attribute',
        'joinTable' => 'practises_attributes',
        'foreignKey' => 'practise_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'attribute_id',
        'unique' => true,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
    )
);
```

**Attribute.php**

```php
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Practise' => array(
        'className' => 'Practise',
        'joinTable' => 'practises_attributes',
        'foreignKey' => 'attribute_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'practise_id',
        'unique' => true,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
    )
);
```

Now I want to find all including a condition on Attributes in my PractiseController.php

**PractiseController.php**

```php
$cond['Attribute.id'] = array(1,2,3);
$this->Practise->find('all', array('conditions' => $cond));
```

Then I get the following error:

Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Attribute.id' in 'where clause'

SQL Query:

SELECT
        `Practise`.`id`,
        `Practise`.`title`,
        `Practise`.`body`, 
    FROM `db`.`practises` AS `Practise`
    WHERE  `Attribute`.`id` IN (1, 2, 3)

How can I make CakePHP also Join the HABTM table into the find query?

Answer (score 0):

You can use contain for example

```
$this->Practise->find('all', array('contain' => 'Attribute.id = whatever'));
```

You can manually join too with:

```html
$options['joins'] = array(
    array('table' => 'practises_attributes',
        'alias' => 'PractiseAttribute',
        'type' => 'INNER',
        'conditions' => array(
            'Attribute.id = whatever',
        )
    ) );
```

Comment: This does not work. In the resulting SQL query there is no join on Attribute and also no other condition on Attribute.id

Comment: Maybe this helps http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#joining-tables